# asset is unable to load in Flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I want to show decoration image in flutter , but there is an error, i don't know why?
I am new to flutter i want to show image as an background of an activity in Flutter.
I attached the  error message below, is any thing is missing or any thing extra in my code, i am unable to understand.

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "Creating account",
    home: new account(),
  ));
}

class account extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _accountState createState() => _accountState();
}

class _accountState extends State<account> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        /// color: Colors.blueGrey,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/image.jpg'), // <-- BACKGROUND IMAGE
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              FlutterLogo(
                size: 100,
                colors: Colors.grey,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: false,
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey),
                  hintText: "Full Name",
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: false,
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey),
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: false,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey),
                  hintText: 'Cell Number',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                obscuringCharacter: "x",
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white),
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                color: Colors.white,
                textColor: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 8, 40, 8),
                onPressed: () => _displaySnackBar(context),
                child: Text(
                  "Create Account",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _displaySnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Aww SnackBar!'));
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/image.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your pubspec.ymal file and add path of your asset folder there.
assets>Images its folder in my app where I have icons or images.

```
assets:
 - assets/images/
```